# Some keys not working until ~10/20min using laptop

Tags: boot, keyboard, keys

I'm having, since 3-4 months some strange problems with my laptop's keyboard. It's an ASUS X401A running Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64.

When I start the notebook, some keys (<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>down arrow</kbd>) don't work at all - (always the same keys). The strange thing is, that if you hold down one of them 1 minute or more, at the end it works, but if you try again, you have to hold it down again for a while (the same happens if holding down another of the 'problematic' keys).

But the big mystery happens when 10 or 20 minutes have passed since laptop started: you have a fully functional keyboard with all keys working (like now, writing this question).

I've tried to boot into the root shell, and didn't had any problem with the keyboard, so I guess that has to be something GUI related. Also, I've tried to look in an `htop` window at the same time that I hold down a key when is not working, but doesn't seem to happen nothing unusual.

I'll really appreciate if someone can help a little with this issue that pisses me off every time that I have hurry to do something.

Thanks all!!

Comment: I have a similar problem on a fresh 14.04 ... some key stop to work here and there ( control/alt/delete ... )

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem on my 16.04