# Some keys randomly not functioning / erratic behaviour

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Suddenly my laptop (with 16.04 LTS) cannot type parentheses <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd>.
I have an Italian keyboard layout, and I've checked it is actually selected.

Strange thing is, the ability to type them seems to come and go randomly.
I am puzzled.

What have I tried:

- checked my keyboard layout, it's the same
- checked this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455245/some-keys-not-working-until-10-20min-using-laptop), seems much like my problem but on different keys. I've tried holding down the parentheses for some time and suddenly I can type them. After a while they stop again.
- checked with `xev`, no output for `(` press, then suddenly I have output.

On italian keyboard, they are typed using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

Comment: What does the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` output?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it outputs `[('xkb', 'it'), ('xkb', 'us')]`

Comment: Looks ok. The only advice I'm able to give is to switch explicitly to _English (US)_ and then back to _Italian_. Doing so has fixed a similar problem for me.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson alas, it was one of the first things I've tried. I begin to suspect a random hardware problem. Thank you anyway :)